# Change Camera shoulder Offset of Cinemachine in script

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNnAq.png)

You want to know how to change Cinemachine camera shoulder offset in script!

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the appropriate component from the `CinemachineVirtualCamera` and set the values on it. Something like that (assuming it's in a `MonoBehaviour`):

```
[SerializeField] private CinemachineVirtualCamera _virtualCamera;

private Cinemachine3rdPersonFollow _3rdPersonFollow;

private void Start()
{
    _3rdPersonFollow = _virtualCamera.GetCinemachineComponent<Cinemachine3rdPersonFollow>();
}

private void SomeMethodOfYoursWhatChangesShoulderOffset()
{
    _3rdPersonFollow.ShoulderOffset = new(x, y, z);
}
```

Same with other components like: `CinemachineTransposer` (Body), `CinemachineBasicMultiChannelPerlin` (Noise), etc.